# What are the default fixed server role members for SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, permissions

What are the default fixed server role **members** for newly created SQL Server 2012 instance using all default options.

As given by

```
EXEC sp_helpsrvrolemember
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a clean install, just do:

```
SELECT role_name = pr.name, member_name = m.name
FROM sys.server_role_members AS r
INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS m
ON r.member_principal_id = m.principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS pr
ON r.role_principal_id = pr.principal_id;
```

Here's what I get:

```
sysadmin    sa
sysadmin    CANUCK\aaronbertrand -- Administrator account I added during setup
sysadmin    NT SERVICE\SQLWriter
sysadmin    NT SERVICE\Winmgmt
sysadmin    NT Service\MSSQL$InstanceName
sysadmin    NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$InstanceName
```

Comment: "CANUCK\" bwahahaha

Comment: @Zane my two main VMs on my primary workstation are `CANUCK` and `HOSER`.